# display an input's value in dialog

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I would like to display in a dialog the number inserted in the inputText.

```
<p:inputText id="nbr"
             type="number" 
             value="#{MB.number}" 
             required="true" 
             label="nbr" />
<p:confirmDialog id="confirmPurchase" 
                 message="Your Database was successfully created. And contains "
                 appendToBody="true" 
                 header="Buy Emails List" 
                 severity="info" 
                 widgetVar="purchase">  
    <a class="boldtext">  
       #{MB.number} 
       <h5> datas</h5> 
    </a>
    <p:commandButton id="confirm" value="Buy"  actionListener="#{MB.buy())}" />  
    <p:commandButton id="decline" 
                     value="Decline" 
                     onclick="purchase.hide();" 
                     type="button" />  
</p:confirmDialog>
```

The code below returns always 0 as a number in the confirm dialog.

**Update1**

the dialog is showing once the action in the commandButton is completed

```
  <p:commandButton value="Extract" update="table nbr" id="ajax" ajax="true" widgetVar="extractButton action="#{MB.search()}" oncomplete="purchase.show();"/>
```

Comment: How exactly are you updating the dialog's content with the submitted number and then opening it? I'm not seeing that anywhere in the code.

Comment: I'm still not seeing anywhere how you're updating the dialog's content. I only see `table` and `nbr` being updated by the command button, but they do not cover the dialog's content which you apparently needed to update. How exactly did you expect the dialog's content to be updated...? By magic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need a `<h:form/>` around your `<p:inputText>` and your `<p:commandButton>`.

Your `<p:commandButton>` should have the attribute `update=":outputUserText"`.

Inside your Dialog, you need a `<p:outputLabel id="outputUserText" value="#{MB.number}"`